# name error: str-index is not defined

Tags: python

```
def get_position (row_index,col_index,size):
    """ (int,int,int) -> int

    Precondition:size >=col_index and size >= row_index

    Return the str_index of the cell with row_index,col_index and size
    >>>get_position (2,2,4)
    5
    >>>get_position (3,4,5)
    13
    """
    str_index = (row_index - 1) * size + col_index - 1  
    return str_index


def make_move( symbol,row_index,col_index,game_board):
    """(str,int,int,str) -> str

    Return the resultant game board with symbol,row_index,col_index and game_board
    >>>make_move("o",1,1,"----")
    "o---"
    >>>make_move("x",2,3,"---------")
    "-----x---"
    """
    length=len(game_board)

    return "-"*(str_index-1)+symbol+"-"*(length-str_index)
```

When I evaluated it, it showed

> "NameError: name 'str_index' is not defined"

I think I have already define str-index.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `str_index` in the `make_move` function. The variable does not exist in the function's scope.

```
def make_move(symbol,row_index,col_index,game_board):
    """(str,int,int,str) -> str

    Return the resultant game board with symbol,row_index,col_index and game_board
    >>>make_move("o",1,1,"----")
    "o---"
    >>>make_move("x",2,3,"---------")
    "-----x---"
    """
    length=len(game_board)
    # I am assuming length is the size for get_position
    str_index = get_position(row_index, col_index, length)

    return "-"*(str_index-1)+symbol+"-"*(length-str_index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code to:

```
return (row_index - 1) *size + col_index - 1
```

and:

```
 str_index =get_position(row_index, col_index, size)
 return "-"*(str_index-1)+symbol+"-"*(length-str_index)
```

**NOTE:** you need to add a `size` parameter to the function or calculate it.